Regex case-insensitive search, but have output match the case in the regex
Recently I rewrote my program to find English words that are made of chemical symbol abbreviations, for example "HErSHeY". I came up with this dynamic regex:
grep -Pi "^($(paste -s -d'|' element_symbols.txt))+$" /usr/share/dict/words

The regex in the paste expands to something like (H|He|Li| ... ). element_symbols.txt is a file starting with
H
He
Li

Sample words list (longest word: formaldehydesulphoxylate - 24 characters)
The -i makes the search case-insensitive, so "Hershey" is in the output, but is there a way to preserve the capitalizations of the letters within the regex, so the output is like "HErSHeY"? This would require replacing the letters in the words file, so maybe something with sed instead.

How do you solve ambiguities, like in yb? Is it Yb (Ytterbium) or YB (Yttrium, Boron)?

If the input is "HErSHeY" and the regex with it -i flag matches, then the output for the match is also "HErSHeY". How do you get "Hershey" in the output?

@RenaudPacalet if there are multiple solutions, any one of them is fine

@Thefourthbird the input is a dictionary file with words like "Hershey". I want the output to change case.

OK, finding one of the many splittings is a complex problem. You'll probably have to implement one form or another of a path finder in a graph (A*, Dijkstra,...). Forget about grep, sed... Try awk, maybe.

@RenaudPacalet DFS (backtracking) is sufficient, no need for more complex grapgh algorithms.

@RenaudPacalet I wrote a python version to demonstrate the idea.

Backtracking is sufficient if and only if your inputs are short strings. If you know what the maximum length id please edit your question and add this important information.

@RenaudPacalet the vast majority of words in /usr/share/dict/words are under 10 letters long. The longest word is 23 characters.

28 on mine. But anyway, you forgot to explain this in your question. Most people will probably think that /usr/share/dict/words is just an example and that you are not really interested in chemical formulas in /usr/share/dict/words. And if the strings you are really interested are hundreds or thousands of characters long things are completely different.

@RenaudPacalet ok, I thought my first sentence made it clear I'm interested in English words.

Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. No links, no images, just plain text. Right now you have a link to some site we could presumably get some information from, and then a link to some other site from which I assume we're supposed to go collect more information, but you haven't provided any expected output even given that. Make it easy for us to help you - just provide sample input and expected output in your question.

Also include your code as that'd help us figure out what you mean by "made of chemical symbol abbreviations" as it's not clear from your question (do all chars have to be part of chemical symbols or just some? If some, how many? If all, can/should they be allowed to overlap? etc. etc.).

@EdMorton see the grep and my python answer. Anyhow all the answerers have figured it out.

You can also implement this in python using the regex module which has the nice additional feature of capturing all matches in a repeating group. This allows for the regex to just be a repeated capture group:
import regex

symbols = open("element_symbols.txt").read().split()
words = open("/usr/share/dict/words").read().split()

pattern = regex.compile(rf'(\L<symbols>)+', symbols=symbols, flags=regex.I)
for word in words:
    match = pattern.fullmatch(word)
    if match is not None:
        res = ''.join(s.title() for s in match.captures(1))
        print(res)

Output on Ubuntu 22.04 with american-english words:
Ac
AcLu
AcTh
Al
Am
Ar
AsCII
AsCIIS
AsPCa
AtP
AtV
Ac
AcCRa
AcHeBe
AcHErNAr
AcHEsON
AcOSTa
...


I'm amazed you managed to find a use for python's title() function

@qwr I'm sure this was their intended use all along! :)

You can solve this problem with Perl, first creating an alternation from the element symbols:
pattern=$(paste -s -d'|' element_symbols.txt)
echo $pattern

Output:
H|He|Li|Be|B|C|N|O|F|Ne|Na|Mg|Al|Si|P|S|Cl|Ar|K|Ca|Sc|Ti|V|Cr|Mn|Fe|Co|Ni|Cu|Zn|Ga|Ge|As|Se|Br|Kr|Rb|Sr|Y|Zr|Nb|Mo|Tc|Ru|Rh|Pd|Ag|Cd|In|Sn|Sb|Te|I|Xe|Cs|Ba|La|Ce|Pr|Nd|Pm|Sm|Eu|Gd|Tb|Dy|Ho|Er|Tm|Yb|Lu|Hf|Ta|W|Re|Os|Ir|Pt|Au|Hg|Tl|Pb|Bi|Po|At|Rn|Fr|Ra|Ac|Th|Pa|U|Np|Pu|Am|Cm|Bk|Cf|Es|Fm|Md|No|Lr|Rf|Db|Sg|Bh|Hs|Mt|Ds|Rg|Cn|Nh|Fl|Mc|Lv|Ts|Og

We then incorporate that alternation into this regex:
\G($pattern)(?=(?1)*$)

This matches:

\G : either start of string or end of the previous match
($pattern) : an element symbol (captured in group 1)
(?=(?1)*$) : a lookahead for some number of element symbols (a repeat of the expression in capture group 1) and then end of line

The anchors on the regex (\G and the lookahead which matches elements up to end of line $) force the regex to match the whole string, which forces the engine to backtrack when a match fails (e.g. when matching He at the beginning of Hershey, or h at the end of Hershey) instead of just skipping to the next match in the string.
Regex demo on regex101
We can then use the \u and \l flags for substitution to upper-case the first letter and lower-case subsequent letters of the matched group (since all element symbols are either a single upper-case letter or an upper-case letter followed by a lower-case letter):
echo 'Hershey' | perl -pE "s/\G($pattern)(?=(?1)*$)/\u\l\$1/gi"

Output:
HErSHeY

Note that when the regex doesn't match i.e. a word can not be made up from element symbols, the word is output unchanged. If you don't want to output anything in that situation, you can wrap the print in an if statement. For example:
tail -96075 /usr/share/dict/words | head -20 | 
perl -nE "if (m/^($pattern)+$/i) { print s/\G($pattern)(?=(?1)*$)/\u\l\$1/gir }"

On my computer this outputs:
HErSeY
HErSHeY

If you want to prioritise matching single or double letter element names, you can sort element_symbols.txt by length prior to making the pattern. For example:
pattern=$(perl -e 'print sort { length($a) <=> length($b) } <>' element_symbols.txt | paste -s -d'|')
echo 'Ho' | perl -nE "if (m/^($pattern)+$/i) { print \$_ =~ s/\G($pattern)(?=(?1)*$)/\u\l\$1/gir }"

pattern=$(perl -e 'print sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } <>' element_symbols.txt | paste -s -d'|')
echo 'Ho' | perl -nE "if (m/^($pattern)+$/i) { print \$_ =~ s/\G($pattern)(?=(?1)*$)/\u\l\$1/gir }"

Output:
HO
Ho


With string Zyzzogeton as its input your perl script prints Zyzzogeton...

@RenaudPacalet that's because it can't be made up of a series of element symbols. I've added a note to that effect to the answer

Ah, OK. I thought the OP wanted to find only the matching words.

@RenaudPacalet I've added code to the answer which will only print matched words. Thanks for pointing this out.

Nice, elegant and fast (about 0.9 second here with the same setup as in my answer).

Bravo. How does the recursive capture group work? Is (?=(?1)|$) equivalent to (?=($pattern)|$)? From the regex101 explanation, there are 5 matches in "Hershey" each with 1 capture group? How does the regex engine know to maximize capture groups for the example "herg", instead of just matching H Er and then not matching g?

@qwr I realised overnight that the regex was wrong as it would allow matching words as long as there were at least 2 symbols at the start. I've corrected that regex, which unfortunately makes it a bit less efficient.

So if I understand correctly, for each element, it matches it if that's after a previous match and is followed by a valid string of elements (the backtracking part), then capitalizes the symbol? It is inefficient if it has to do that for each element, but creative.

@qwr that is correct. It isn't as fast as pure text processing such as in the other answers but as Renaud said, it's not that much slower than his solution.

@qwr there's also a way of doing this with python regex which would be more efficient, although not directly suited to command line usage. I can write it up if you're interested

@Nick is a python regex more capable than PCRE? The current solution is sufficiently fast for my needs.

@qwr the python regex library can capture all matches for a repeating group. This would allow just matching ^($pattern)+$ and then processing each match.

Oh it's not the builtin re module. Yes that would be very nice and in the spirit of the question.

@qwr I've posted sample code as a separate answer.

As your strings are short enough to allow backtracking we can probably also repeatedly split the string in 2 sub-strings: a 1 or 2 characters head and a tail, check if the head and the tail match, print the head and continue with the tail.
Example with any awk (priority to 2 letters symbols):
awk '
  { lc = tolower($0) }
  FNR == NR { r = r ? (r "|" lc) : lc; e[lc]; next }
  FNR == 1 { r = "^(" r ")+$" }
  lc ~ r {
    while(lc) {
      h1 = substr(lc, 1, 1); h2 = substr(lc, 2, 1); t2 = substr(lc, 3)
      printf("%s", toupper(h1))
      if(((h1 h2) in e) && ((t2 == "") || (t2 ~ r))) { printf("%s", h2); lc = t2 }
      else lc = h2 t2
    }
    print ""
  }' element_symbols.txt /usr/share/dict/words
AcAcIIn
AcAcIn
AcAlYCAl
...
YURuPArY
YUS
YUSTaGa
YVONNe

This is super fast: about 1/3 second on an Intel quad-core i7 at 3.6 GHz, 16 GB memory, with GNU awk 5.3.0, all chemical symbols, a 235976 words /usr/share/dict/words, and the output redirected to a file.
However it looks sub-optimal because the lc ~ r1 check already did the job that we redo step by step. If we had a way to access intermediate states of the initial lc ~ r1 check we could expect higher performance. GNU awk extends the match function to collect capture groups in an array; let's give it a try:
awk '
  { lc = tolower($0) }
  FNR == NR { r = r ? (r "|" lc) : lc; next }
  FNR == 1 { r = "^(" r ")((" r ")*)$" }
  lc ~ r {
    while(match(lc, r, a)) {
      printf("%s%s", toupper(substr(a[1], 1, 1)), substr(a[1], 2))
      lc = a[2]
    }
    print ""
  }' element_symbols.txt /usr/share/dict/words

This takes about 8 seconds (25 times the first version). The match function of GNU awk is not as efficient as we expected...
A more aggressive version that uses a very long regex with as many (ac|...|zr)? as the length of the longest string, to call match only once per string:
awk '
  ARGIND == 2 { max = max < length ? length : max; next }
  { lc = tolower($0) }
  ARGIND == 1 { s = s ? (s "|" lc) : lc; next }
  ARGIND == 3 && FNR == 1 {
    for(i = 1; i <= max; i++) r = r "(" s ")?"
    r = "^" r "$"
  }
  match(lc, r, a) {
    for(i = 1; length(a[i]); i++)
      printf("%s%s", toupper(substr(a[i], 1, 1)), substr(a[i], 2))
    print ""
  }' element_symbols.txt /usr/share/dict/words /usr/share/dict/words

This takes about 18 seconds (55 times the first version). Very long regex are also very slow to process.
Note that version 1 differs from the 2 others because the greediness of the matching is different. With input string Ho version 1 prints Ho (Holmium). The others print HO (Hydrogen, Oxygen).

Text operations will almost always be faster than regex. Thanks for the benchmarking info

What do you mean by head and tail match? Do you mean the head is a symbol, and the tail is a valid string of symbols?

This might work for you (GNU sed):
match=$(sed '/.../d;s/^.$/z&/;H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/.*/echo "&"|sort/e;s/^z//mg;s/\n/|/g' symbols)
lookup=$(sed 's/[A-Za-z]\+/\l&:&/g;s/.*/|&|/' <<<"$match")
sed -E '/^\<('"$match"')+\>$/I!d
        s/.*/\L&/;s/$/\n'"$lookup"'\n/
        :a;s/^('"$match"')([^\n]*\n.*\|\1:([^|]+).*)/\2\3/i;ta
        /^\n/!{s/(.*)(.)/\2\1/;ta}
        s/.*\n//' /usr/share/dict/words

Create two variables for comfort.
The variable $match is a regexp for all the element symbols sorted and separated by an alternation symbol. The single character symbols are placed last so as to allow greed to work.
The variable $lookup is the cased version of the match regexp.
First match a word and if it doesn't delete it.
Lower case the word.
Append the lookup table.
Iterate through the word, replacing each symbol by its uppercase complement.
Oops, the regex was too greedy reduce and redress the situation and go again.
Remove the introduced newlines and lookup table and print the result.
N.B. Repeated substitutions take place until the original word is consumed and a subsequent substitution encounters the introduced newline. The result appears at the end of the pattern space delimited by the second introduced newline.

On reflection a simpler solution is:
match=$(sed '/.../d;s/^.$/z&/;H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/.*/echo "&"|sort/e;s/^z//mg;s/\n/|/g' symbols)
sed -E '/^('$match')+$/I!d
       s/.*/\L&\n/
       :a;s/^('$match')([^\n]*\n.*)/\2\u\1/i;ta
       /^\n/!{s/(.*)(.)/\2\1/;ta}
       s/.*\n//' /usr/share/dict/words


Wow, that is a lot to unpack. Since I'm not familiar with sed, how does it do the backtracking?

@qwr Rudimentary backtracking takes place at the 2nd line from the bottom. If the word has not been consumed the previous match was too greedy thus the last character of the match is replaced and the substitutions resumed.Since the word has already successfully been matched by the first regexp, for each symbol there are only at most two choices, a two character or a single character both of which start with the same initial character. If a subsequent match fails after a two character match the previous match must have been too long and can thus be reduced.

Here is my example Python implementation, forgoing regex completely and using simple backtracking with generators (cleaner code and lets me stop at the first solution). I am still interested in a regex-based solution that can build up candidate solutions while reading lowercase input.
symbols = open("element_symbols.txt").read().split()
words = open("/usr/share/dict/words").read().split()

def munch(w):
    if not w: yield ''; return
    for s in symbols:
        if w.startswith(s.lower()):
            for z in munch(w[len(s):]):
                yield s + z

for word in words:
    try: print(next(munch(word.lower())))
    except StopIteration: pass

On my laptop running takes 5.7 seconds, but 0.8 with pypy. CPython in my experience is very slow with many string operations.
